# Rails - how to cache data for server use, serving multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class method (placed in    `/app/lib/`) which performs some heavy calculations and sub-http requests until a result is received.

The result isn't too dynamic, and requested by multiple users accessing a specific view in the app.

So, I want to schedule a periodic run of the method (using cron and Whenever gem), store the results somewhere in the server using JSON format and, by demand, read the results alone to the view.

How can this be achieved? what would be the **correct** way of doing that?

What I currently have:

```
def heavyMethod
   response = {}
   # some calculations, eventually building the response
   File.open(File.expand_path('../../../tmp/cache/tests_queue.json', __FILE__), "w") do |f|
      f.write(response.to_json)
   end
end
```

and also a corresponding method to read this file.

I searched but couldn't find an example of achieving this using Rails cache convention (and not some private code that I wrote), on data which isn't related with ActiveRecord.

Thanks!

Comment: rails cache - memcached.`cache.set` in ur periodic job, and `cache.get` in ur requests. U need to be careful about what happens in cold start. U might want to run that process once upon server start, or u can do it so that the view runs it if the entry is missing.. but that would be bad for experience

Comment: [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores) provide many cache methods and you also can use redis or memcache to save you json data, it could be more quickly that read a file.

Comment: @KarthikT, thanks a lot for both answers. In fact, I'd like that none of the users will experience the loading time of the method. i.e., I'd like to perform that background job once every 15 minuets, cache it, and fetch the data of the cached result in my rails view. Also, as to cold start, running at server start seems indeed a better idea (using a rake task or calling that method from the instance initializer). Could you please post an answer with en example of how to implement this using memcached methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should work fine, but using `Rails.cache` should be cleaner and a bit faster. [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores) provides enough information about `Rails.cache` and how to get it to work with `memcached`, let me summarize how I would use it in your case

**Heavy method**

```
def heavyMethod
   response = {}
   # some calculations, eventually building the response
   Rails.cache.write("heavy_method_response", response)
end
```

**Request**

```
response = Rails.cache.fetch("heavy_method_response")
```

The only problem here is that when ur server starts for the first time, the cache will be empty. Also if/when memcache restarts.

One advantage is that somewhere on the flow, the data u pass in is marshalled into storage, and then unmartialled on the way out. Meaning u can pass in complex datastructures, and dont need to serialize to json manually.

Edit: memcached will clear your item if it runs out of memory. Will be very rare since its using a LRU (i think) algoritm to expire things, and I presume you will use this often.
To prevent this,

1. set `expires_in` larger than your cron period,
2. change your fetch code to call the `heavy_method` if ur fetch fails (like `Rails.cache.fetch("heavy_method_response") {heavy_method}`, and change `heavy_method` to just return the object.
3. Use something like `redis` which will not delete items.

Comment: thanks for this answer!
just to make sure- (1) calling this method again will refresh the stores cache with the updated info? (2) is there any possibility the the    `fetch` method will fail? or once this method run at the server start the primary info shall exist until server shutdown?
thanks,

Comment: it will fail if memcached goes down, or if u are not using memcached, whatever cache you use. Do not use the default memory store cuz that is local to each process

Comment: So how can I make sure the latest value I stores doesn't erase from the cache, but can only be replaced with a new, periodically calculated updated value? (i saw there is a    `expires_in` argument, but setting it to something like   `1.year` seems the wrong way to do so...

Comment: ah hmm, forgot that bit. memcached will remove your item if it runs out of memory. `expires_in` of your cron duration should be sufficient. Alternatively, if you are willing to do the heavy_method in the off chance this happens, you can do that inside a block to `fetch`, else, use something like redis which I think is more for data that cant be wiped like this.